# How to make a Pop-up table appear in Workshop Palantir Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I want a pop up to appear showing some stats on the load of a module in Workshop, Palantir. Please help how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workshop just released a new feature that allows you to set a “modal” layout component. Whereas previously you could only add a “drawer” that button now offers to add an “overlay” and in the config you can choose either the drawer or modal layout.

From there you can add widgets and otherwise build the content and then trigger it to open and close with Events, just like the drawer.